# Is it possible to display color in the Java Console? (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, colors

I'm currently working on a program that checks Id's. It prints everything in the console. If the Id is valid then I want it to be green else red. Is there code to do this? I am currently working in Eclipse.

I am not looking for Eclipse plugins, but more so maybe a library I can include or Java specific code. This has nothing to do with ANSI Scala or whatever it is.

Comment: If it has nothing to do with eclipse, why do you mention it in the first place?

Comment: @dr0i I'm not saying it has nothing to do with Eclipse. I'm saying im not looking for a plugin. I mentioned Eclipse as my IDE thinking maybe other IDE's consoles behave differently.

Comment: This can only be done using a plugin if you are displaying on an Eclipse console.

Comment: @StephenC how about any other IDE (JGrasp, Netbeans, IntelliJ)?

Comment: If an IDE doesn't already support writing colour to its console, then that functionality *could* only be implemented via a plugin.  (And I don't know if it actually *can* ...)

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for your input